# Implement Serialisation in more than 100 files

Tags: java, serialization, serializable

I have to write implement serializable in more than 200 java files. Is there any tool to help since it is very repetitive work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use find and replace with a regex in your IDE and clean up e.g. replace `public class (.*) {` with `public class $1 implements java.io.Serializable {`